# How do I add a reaction to the message I just sent

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a task function in one of my Cog files like the one below. It is not a command, it just gets run as a background task every 30 seconds. I want to add a reaction to the message I just sent. How  can I do this?

```
async def _say_hello(self, channelId):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(channelId)
    await channel.send("Hi everyone")
    await channel.add_reaction(':heart:') # This part gives me an error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending a message, you can plop it into a variable and use it as a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object, like so:

```py
async def _say_hello(self, channelId):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(channelId)
    msg = await channel.send("Hi everyone")
    await msg.add_reaction('❤') # heart's unicode is \u2764
```

When adding a reaction, you want to use the actual emoji (if your editor supports it), or the unicode, which you can get from [this](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_emoticons.html) website.

## Custom Emojis

```py
async def _say_hello(self, channelId):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(channelId)
    msg = await channel.send("Hi everyone")
    emoji = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="emojiname")
    # emoji = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.emojis, id=112233445566778899) alternative method
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

## discord.utils [usage](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get):

```py
obj = discord.utils.get(iter, attr="something")

# examples
member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=112233445566778899)
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name="general")
```

When looking for a specific object, you can use any attribute the object has. Refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#) if you need any prompts.

Comment: For some reason it tells me `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`. Is there a way to hardcode the emoji as a string rather than getting then asking the bot to go fetch the emoji object

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Sorry forgot about the emoji part! Edited my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Also added in custom emoji functionality.